# Docker: Unable to commit a built docker image

Tags: docker, dockerfile

After running `docker build .` command, trying to commit the built image, but receiving the below error

```
Step 12 : CMD activator run
 ---> Using cache
 ---> efc82ff1ca9c
Successfully built efc82ff1ca9c
osboxes@osboxes:~/play-websocket-java-master$ docker commit -m "add dashboard" -a "Somasundaram Sekar" efc82ff1ca9c  somasundaramsekar/play-activator-1.3.0:v2
Error response from daemon: No such container: efc82ff1ca9c
```

However I can use `docker run` with the same container id, but only commit fails with

> No such Container

if it's ok any help, I have logged into docker.io and gitlab registry from the same machine, before the error started occuring

I was able to do the same until yesterday, but not sure why the failure occurs now

Answer (score 1):

If you can [`docker run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/), but not [`docker commit`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/), that means the id `efc82ff1ca9c` represents an **image**, *not* a container.

That would explains why container-related operations fail.

Those "Successfully built" ids represents the intermediate containers committed into an intermediate image.
See `docker images -a` output.

Answer (score 0):

Commit should be run with containers ids not image ids:

From https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/:

> It can be useful to commit a container’s file changes or settings **into a new image**.

`efc82ff1ca9c` is an image id.

You can tag the image (using docker tag command) but not commit it (since commit is for creating new images base on running containers).

Comment: Isn't it what I, in essence, mentioned in my answer?

Comment: Sorry, I some how missed it. I up voted your answer. I will live mine as well since it contains quote from the documentation and info information about tagging option.